# Css - Custom style on checkbox not working

Tags: javascript, css, checkbox, kendo-grid

First off I have a kendo grid. Now I am dynamically adding a checkbox to the DataSource like below:

```
var chkBox =  "<input type='checkbox' id='chUpload'/><label for='chUpload'><a href='#' id='cbChoose'></a>test</label>";

var uploadedFiles = 
[
    { 
        facility: "Sunrise medical Laboratories", 
        documentName:  "Lab Results",
        documentType: "PDF",
        selected: chkBox
    }
];
```

Following are the styles implemented on the checkbox:

```
input[type="checkbox"]
{
    display:none;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label a
{
    display:inline-block;
    width:14px;
    height:14px;
    margin:-1px 4px 0 0;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background:url('../images/checkBox.png') right top no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
    float:right;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label a 
{
    background:url('../images/checkBox.png') -1px top no-repeat;
}
```

> **I found that these styles work on other checkboxes which I added to a
>   panelbar's tabs, but in the grid, nothing is displayed.**

I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/97gqZ/25/) with the black boxes being the styled checkbox. 
I have hidden the `display:none;` in the css to see where all textboxes are. If it is in use, no check custom boxes are displayed in the grid.

***Any ideas why?***

Comment: you need to remove the template value as that is getting placed instead of the chkBox variable. i.e `
        template: "<input type='checkbox' style='margin-right:23px; margin-top:0px;'  />"`

Comment: I just noticed that I have both field and template. When the template is removed,  the `field` interprets chkBox as a String and not as html code as seen here: (http://jsfiddle.net/97gqZ/30/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.

```
template: "<input type='checkbox' style='margin-right:23px; margin-top:0px;'  />"
```

should be:

```
template: "#= selected #"
```

which was a simple mistake of mine.

Here is a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/97gqZ/37/).

Comment: i do understand now... deleted my answer.